# URL redirect throws a 405 Method not found when be redirected to other application in different app pool

Tags: c#, iis, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

I'm working on rerouting a particular route to a different Application in the same IIS site but it sits in a different app pool. Although I have gotten this to rewrite the URL it doesn't allow it rewrite to a app that is in a different app pool without using ARR(Application Request Routing) or so I've read.

I'm currently trying to just do a redirect and seems to be directing fine for GET request but when I make POST calls too it it fails with "Method not allowed". Using fiddler it is doing a GET when I send down a POST.

If anyone can make some suggestions if it is possible for this to just redirect the URL but keep the same request body and method?

My "rewrite" is as follows with some minor details changed

```
    <rewrite>
    <rules>
    <rule name="REST1 to REST2" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^REST1/Service/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="site.com/REST2/Service/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
     </rules>
     </rewrite>
```

This seems to redirect the URL just fine but not the method or request body.
Is this something I'm going to have to do with a rewrite? If so any suggestion for doing this when sending the request to a app in a different app pool.

Answer (score 0):

Your rule will respond with a 301 status code redirection which the client (I assume browser) then decides what to do with.  If your client is not a browser, you could maybe tell it to replay the same request to the new endpoint.  Otherwise Rewrite (or Rewrite + ARR if you want cross AppPools) is how you'd do this.

Answer (score 0):

Please try changing the action type to Rewrite instead of Redirect.

A redirect always results redirect header being sent to the browser.  This changes the URL in the browser address bar, and the browser then issues an HTTP GET for the new address.  With an HTTP GET, no form/post data are ever sent; all arguments are assumed to be in the URL querystring.

If you'd like to avoid the redirect and use a true rewrite, change your web.config to use action=rewrite.  Using this method, no redirect header is sent back to the browser, the browser address bar never changes, and IIS simply redirects the current request stream to a different location.